# Excel: Hyperlink to jump to current date

Tags: excel

I got an Excel sheet with all the dates of the year. And on the Top i want to do a link to jump to the current date... I got this

```
=HYPERLINK(VERGLEICH(HEUTE();D:D;0))
```

Thats just giving me the number of the line, where the current date is located. 
By the way: Vergleich = Match // Heute = Today

How do I do that?

Comment: by 'jump', do you mean scroll?

Comment: Yes. :) And i forgot to mention: D is the column, where my dates are

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `HYPERLINK` shall link to a cell, `D12` for example, then the hyperlink address must be `#D12`. So `=HYPERLINK("#D12")` will work.

If the `12` shall be variable according to a matched value, todays date for example, then this value must be concatenated into the hyperlink address.

Example: Column `D` contains date values. One of those is todays date.

```
=HYPERLINK("#D"&MATCH(TODAY(),D:D,0))
```

German Excel:

```
=HYPERLINK("#D"&VERGLEICH(HEUTE();D:D;0))
```

This works only if  in column D are date values, not  strings, and really date values only, without time, and todays date is among them.

Comment: Thanks for that, but when i create that hyperlink it says: #NV (Error: Value is not available) :/

Comment: Then todays date is not found in column D. Are you sure there are date values, not  strings, and really date values only without time and todays date is among them?

Comment: Wow I am stupid :D I am preparing that for 2017... So it's pretty obvious that todays date is not found... Stupid me. Tried it with 2016. worked :) thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

Say we have dates in column **D** like:

[image]

This formula will give the proper row for the cell containing today's date:

```
=MATCH(TODAY(),D:D,0)
```

We can use this in the hyperlink formula:

```
=HYPERLINK("#D" & MATCH(TODAY(),D:D,0),"today")
```

For example:

[image]

Comment: Same problem as above... :/ #NV (Error: Value is not available)